# Correct formatting for mixed model design with lmer() in R

Tags: r, lm, lme4

I'm trying to identify the correct format for a Mixed Effects model using `lmer()`.  The three models below are all trying to achieve the same thing - a simple fixed-effects model - and so two must be wrong.

In the models, `shoppers` is data on consumer spending for a commercial centre. There is a general inverse-square distance relationship that describes how consumers are distributed from the centre.  This is reflected in a `gravity` model, a matrix that weights closer district zones higher than those further away to model the effects of distance.  `Population` size for residential district is also given.  I think that `r3` should be the correct format, but it yields a higher AIC score than `r2`.  Any idea why this might be, and which is correct?

```
> r1 <- lmer(shoppers / gravity ~ population + (1 | District), data = d)
> r2 <- lmer(shoppers * gravity ~ population + (1 | District), data = d)
> r3 <- lmer(shoppers ~ gravity / population + (1 | District), data = d)
> 
> summary(r1)@AICtab
      AIC      BIC    logLik deviance  REMLdev
 38154.25 38180.12 -19073.12 38132.84 38146.25
> summary(r2)@AICtab
      AIC     BIC    logLik deviance  REMLdev
 6504.574 6530.45 -3248.287 6470.837 6496.574
> summary(r3)@AICtab
      AIC     BIC    logLik deviance  REMLdev
 14965.16 14997.5 -7477.579 14933.57 14955.16
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your models are not comparable as they have different response.

Comment: I agree with @Luciano, and I'm somewhat amazed that the first two models worked at all ...

Comment: `gravity/population` probably doesn't make any sense, maybe `gravity*population`?  http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models may be helpful.

Comment: Thank for comments. If there is any confusion, I'm not trying to compare models, I'm trying to establish which is correct.  I thought the first two would be equivalent to performing the same operations they describe (left of the '~') outside lmer and feeding in the new figures. Regarding 'gravity/population', this is exactly the operation outside lmer that does account for the spatial effects of the variance, balancing distance and population size. So I take it I've been misunderstanding the syntax of lmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model `shoppers ~ gravity / population + (1 | District)` uses `shoppers` as dependent variable and the main effect of `gravity` and the interaction between `gravity` and `population` (`gravity:population`) as two fixed effects:

```
model1 <- lmer(shoppers ~ gravity / population + (1 | District), data = d)
```

If you want to test the interaction, your model should include the corresponding main effects too.

If you instead want to test the effect of the result of `gravity` divided by `population` as single fixed effect, use the following formula:

```
model2 <- lmer(shoppers ~ as.numeric(gravity / population) + (1 | District), data = d)
```

Maybe you want to try the model `shoppers ~ gravity * population + (1 | District)`. There are three fixed effects in this model: The main effects of both `gravity` and `population` and the interaction between these variables (`gravity:population`):

```
model3 <- lmer(shoppers ~ gravity * population + (1 | District), data = d)
```

The selection of the model should depend on the underlying theory and your questions/hypotheses.

Since these models employ the same dependent variable (`shoppers`), i.e., they are identical left of the `~` sign, you can compare the AIC values.

```
anova(model1, model2, model3)
```